# Dispatching to redux store after retrieving data from FireBase Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, firebase-authentication, dispatch

I am using a PressableOpacity button to initiate a function that retrieves a UserID from A firebase firestore.

After setting my state the data does not seem to be sent to the store because I cannot retrieve the userID later on from the store on a different page.

Why is userID not being sent to my redux store?

```
this.state = {
           id: ''
        }
```

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupbutton}>
       <Button
           color='white'
           title="Log in"
           onPress={(payload) => this.handleLogin()}

            />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
Firebase.auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(async cred => {
               const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
               const userId = currentUser["uid"];
                  this.setState({
                     id: userId
                   })
                 
                this.props.id(cred.user.id);
                return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                    test: 'test'
                })
            })
            .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddProfiles'))

             const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            this.setState({
             id: currentUser['uid']
            })

           this.props.id(this.state.id);
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        counter: state.counter,
        value: state.id
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        //increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'email' },'email111'),
        id: (value) => dispatch({ type: 'id', payload: value })
    }
};
```